# How can I restrict SlickGrid to having a max of a single row highlighted at any particular time?

Tags: slickgrid

I want to allow only a single row to ever be highlighted in my grid. If a user selects a row, then selects a new row, only the new row will be highlighted (also, multiselect row is off).

In attempting to do this, I set this event:

```
grid.onSelectedRowsChanged.subscribe(function() {  grid.setSelectedRows([1,2,3]); });
```

although it appears to work, it is very slow (3 seconds to execute for only 50 total rows) and in chrome 13, it returns 2 errors:

1) Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
and

2) a huge error trace:

```
error>
c.fn.c.pushStack:23
c.each.c.fn:99
getCellNode:2277
removeCellCssStyles:1506
setCellCssStyles:1518
handleSelectedRangesChanged:925
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRowsslick.grid.js:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:125
trigger:789
handleSelectedRangesChanged:927
notify:125
setSelectedRanges:72
setSelectedRows:2478
grid.onAddNewRow.subscribe.item:546
notify:12
```

is there an better way to achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: This started happening to me too.  It's really frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum call stack is caused by the circular function calls.

You first trigger the the `onSelectedRowsChanged` event (probably via onClick) which will call your function above. But then your function calls `setSelectedRows` which will set the selected rows and then trigger the `onSelectedRowsChanged`. This will continue happening until the JS engine reaches the maximum call stack and then stops (after all, we don't want to crash the browser).

I think the only solution is to write your own RowSelectionModel and perform the grid.setSelectedRows() in there.